# SwiftUI сам обновляет(повторно вызывает конструктор) View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Только начал изучать Swift, есть вот такая вьюха:

```swift
import SwiftUI


struct AddAddressView: View {
    @ObservedObject public var model = AddressViewModel()
    @ObservedObject public var storage: PackageListViewModel;
    
    init(storage: PackageListViewModel) {
        self.storage = storage
        print("init AddAddressView")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Main information")) {
                    TextField("My address", text: self.$model.name).onChange(of: self.model.name) { _ in
                        self.storage.change(address: self.model)
                    }
                    TextField("", text: self.$model.address)
                }
                
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Change address")
        }
    }
}
```

Когда изменяется поле `self.$model.name` вызывается `self.storage.change(model)`, вот неполный код этого хранилища:

```swift
class PackageListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var list = [AddressViewModel]()
    
    public func change(address: AddressViewModel) {
        self.list.append(address)
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что когда я изменяю что-то в поле для ввода страница реинициализируется(в консоли принтуется `init AddAddressView`)

На всякий случай `AddressViewModel`:

```swift
import Foundation

class AddressViewModel: Identifiable, ObservableObject, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    
    @Published public var address: String = ""
    @Published public var name: String = ""

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    static func ==(lhs: AddressViewModel, rhs: AddressViewModel) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

what is it???

*update:*
Попробовал вот так:

```swift
init(storage: PackageListViewModel, model: AddressViewModel) {
    storage.list.append(model)
    print("init AddAddressView")
        
    self.model = AddressViewModel()
    self.storage = PackageListViewModel()
}
```

Бесконечный луп здравствуй, теперь вообще не понимаю что здесь происходит.

```swift
init(storage: PackageListViewModel, model: AddressViewModel) {
    print("init AddAddressView")
    
    self.model = model
    self.storage = storage //PackageListViewModel()
}
```

Вот так почему-то все нормально. Получается, изменив внешний объект почему-то вью пересоздается. Почему?

Answer (score 0):

Дело было в том, что родительский элемент следил рендерился в зависимости от этого листа, решение было таким:

было:

```swift
struct PackageListView: View {
    @ObservedObject public var model = PackageListViewModel()
    // ...
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink(destination: AddAddressView(storage: model, model: AddressViewModel())) {
    // ...
```

стало:

```swift
struct PackageListView: View {
    @ObservedObject public var model = PackageListViewModel()
    private var newAddrModel: AddressViewModel
    init() {
        self.newAddrModel = AddressViewModel()
    }
    // ...
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink(destination: AddAddressView(storage: model, model: newAddrModel)) {
    // ...
```